# Input from file producing garbage

Tags: c++, file, input, garbage

I am trying to make a program keeping track of average temperatures and rainfall. I have a text file with four integers per line (each line represents a day), and I want to read one line at a time and deal with each of the variables per day.

The problem is that I can't seem to read the file values into variables. When I print the variables to the screen, it just prints garbage. PS. In the code beneath, I try to deal with just the first line of the file. How can I read from every line, one at a time?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
    {
    string fileName = "metrolog.dta";
    string buffer;
    int numOfDays = 0,
        dayNumber,
        maxTemp,
        minTemp,
        rainfall,
        tempDiff,
        tempDiffMax,
        totalMaxTemp,
        totalMinTemp,
        totalRainfall;

ifstream infile(fileName);

    while(getline(infile, buffer))
        if(!buffer.empty())
            ++numOfDays;

    cout << "Number of entries: " << numOfDays << endl;

    infile >> dayNumber >> minTemp >> maxTemp >> rainfall;
    cout << dayNumber << " " << minTemp << " " << maxTemp << " " << rainfall << endl;


    return 0;
    }
```

The file looks like this:

```
 1      9      12       23  
 2      8       9       20  
 3      7      13       18  
 4      8      10       15  
 5      7      13       10  
 6      6       9        8  
 7      5       8       12  
 8      4      10        6  
 9      3       9       12  
10      4       7        6
```

Comment: You never read the variables in,

Comment: @Untitled123 She/he does. `infile >> dayNumber >> minTemp >> maxTemp >> rainfall;`.

Comment: @cad Not after reading the whole file, and discarding it. Since the line that you pasted would be executed, only after the whole file was already read.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Alright, but she/he makes the attempt. I read it Untitled123's comment as "these variables are uninitialized and never tried to be initialized."

Comment: To be honest, I just skimmed the contents of the while loop and found them to be lacking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is

```
while(getline(infile, buffer))
        if(!buffer.empty())
            ++numOfDays;
```

Reads until the end of the file.  Then on your next read

```
infile >> dayNumber >> minTemp >> maxTemp >> rainfall;
```

Nothing happens since the `eof` flag is set so

```
cout << dayNumber << " " << minTemp << " " << maxTemp << " " << rainfall << endl;
```

Prints out whatever garbage is in the variables since you do not initialize them to any particular variable.  You need to reset the stream pointer back to the beginning of the file.  You can do that with

```
infile.clear(); // clear error flags
infile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg); // set stream back to the beginning
```

Another way to do this would be to read the file and count the lines at the same time.  You can do that with

```
while (infile >> dayNumber >> minTemp >> maxTemp >> rainfall)
{
    ++numOfDays;
    cout << dayNumber << " " << minTemp << " " << maxTemp << " " << rainfall << endl;
}
```

But this will only work if you can print out the number of entries after the list.

Comment: of course the right solution is simply to count the number of days as the file is read the first time around and output that afterwards.